A Question about the Product of the Slopes of Two Line Segments within an Ellipse
$\textbf{Update:}$ I have posted a new question for similar property in hyperbola, and I give two analytic solutions to it. More thoughts, answers, comments are welcomed. Here is the link to New Post.

I am doing a problem in analytic geometry, and here is the problem:
Suppose there is an ellipse as is shown in the picture below, with $OA = OC = a, OB = OD = b, a>b>0, OF = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ and $F$ being one of its two foci. And there is a straight line crossing $F$ with its slope being $k $ and intersecting with the ellipse, with $E_1, E_2$ being their intersection points. Let $E_1$ be $(x_1, y_1)$ and $E_2$ be $(x_2,y_2)$. Then let the slope of $E_1 C$ be $k_1$ and that of $E_2 F$ be $k_2$. Prove that $k_1 k_2$ is determined only by $a$ and $b$.

For this problem, my solution is to use $\textbf{analytic way}$ to do brutal computation, and I have divided it into 3 cases. Here is my solution:
$\textbf{Case $1$:}$ $k \neq 0$ and $k \neq \infty$
Given that the slope of the straight line is $k$ and we have $F: (\sqrt{a^2 - b^2},0)$, we have the function of this straight line is
\begin{equation} y = k(x - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}) \tag{1} \end{equation}
And given the information about the ellipse in the question, we have the function for the ellipse is
\begin{equation} \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{2} \end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation} b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \tag{3} \end{equation}
And then, combining $(1)$ and $(3)$ together, we have
$$\begin{cases}
   y = k(x - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2})\\
   \\
   b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2
   \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{aligned}   &\Rightarrow b^2 x^2 + a^2 k^2 (x - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2})^2 = a^2 b^2\\
                    &\Rightarrow (a^2 k^2 + b^2) x^2 - 2a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} x + a^2 k^2(a^2-b^2) - a^2 b^2 = 0 \\
                    &\Rightarrow  \begin{cases}
                                  x_1 x_2 = \frac{a^2 k^2(a^2-b^2) - a^2b^2}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} \\
                                    \\
                                  x_1 + x_2 = \frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a^2 k^2 + b^2}
                                  \end{cases}                      
\end{aligned}$$
So we get
\begin{equation}x_1 x_2 = \frac{a^2 k^2(a^2-b^2) - a^2b^2}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} \tag{4} \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}x_1 + x_2 = \frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} \tag{5} \end{equation}
Then since we have $E_1: (x_1, y_1), E_2: (x_2, y_2), C: (a, 0)$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
                k_1 k_2 &= \frac{y_1}{x_1 - a} \frac{y_2}{x_2 - a}\\
                        &= k^2 \frac{(x_1 - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2})(x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2})}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2}\\
                        &=  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 - b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2} 
\end{aligned}$$
This means
\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 =  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 - b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2} \tag{6} \end{equation}
And then we plug $(4)$ and $(5)$ into $(6)$, and we get
$$\begin{aligned}
                k_1 k_2 &=  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 - b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2}\\
                        &=  k^2 \frac{\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2-b^2) - a^2b^2}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} + \frac{(a^2 - b^2)(a^2 k^2 + b^2)}{a^2 k^2 + b^2}}{\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2-b^2) - a^2b^2}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} - a\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a^2 k^2 + b^2} + \frac{a^2(a^2 k^2 + b^2)}{a^2 k^2 + b^2}}\\
                        &= k^2 \frac{-a^2 b^2 - a^2 k^2 (a^2-b^2) + a^2 k^2 (a^2-b^2) + b^2 (a^2-b^2)}{a^4 k^2 - a^2 k^2 b^2 - a^2 b^2 - 2 a^3 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}+ a^4 k^2 + a^2 b^2}\\
                        &= k^2 \frac{-b^4}{k^2 (a^4 - a^2 b^2 - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}+ a^4)}\\
                        &=  \frac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}- a^2 b^2 }
\end{aligned}$$
Hence we have
\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 = \frac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}- a^2 b^2. } \tag{7} \end{equation}
$\textbf{Case $2$:}$ $k=0$
In this case, the straight line is $x-$axis, and we have either $E_1, A$ become the same point or $E_2, C$ become the same point, and this means at least one of $k_1, k_2$ doesn't exist, and therefore $k_1 k_2$ doesn't exist.
$\textbf{Case $3$:}$ $k=\infty $
In this case, the straight line crossing $F$ is perpendicular to $x-$axis, so we have
$$\begin{cases}
              b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \\
                                          \\
              x = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}
  \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{aligned} 
                &\Rightarrow y^2 = \frac{b^4}{a^2}\\
                &\Rightarrow y = \pm \frac{b^2}{a}
  \end{aligned}$$
So without loss of generality, we set $E_1: (\sqrt{a^2-b^2}, \frac{b^2}{a}), E_2: (\sqrt{a^2-b^2}, \frac{-b^2}{a})$. Therefore, we have
$$\begin{aligned} 
                    k_1 k_2 &= \frac{\frac{b^2}{a} - 0}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a} \frac{\frac{-b^2}{a} - 0}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a}\\
                            &= \frac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a)^2}
  \end{aligned}$$
$\textbf{Conclusion}$
Thus, finally we get
$$k_1 k_2 = \begin{cases}
                         \dfrac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} - a^2 b^2}, k \neq 0 \land k \neq \infty \\
                            \\
                         N/A, k = 0 \\
                            \\
                         \dfrac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a)^2}, k = \infty 
              \end{cases}$$
and this shows that $k_1 k_2$ is indeed determined only by $a$ and $b$.
$\textbf{Question}$
As we can see from the computational process above, it requires considerable time and effort to carry on all these stuffs through the analytic way. Therefore, my question is, whether we can do this problem with simpler ways, for example through the geometric and/or optical properties of an ellipse? I am not familiar with the geometric and optical properties of conic sections, so I hope someone can give me some advice on solving this problem with better ways. Thanks!

$\textbf{P.S.}$ As @Blue has pointed out in his answer, if we set the eccentricity of the ellipse to be $e=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}$, then we can conclude that
$$\dfrac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} - a^2 b^2} = \dfrac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a)^2} = -(1+e)^2$$
and this may help you relate this problem to the geometric/optical properties of an ellipse.

Can you check the last line of the statement of the problem? When you say the tangent, I guess you mean the slope?? Also, do you mean the slopes of $E_1C$ and $E_2C$? If that is the case, when you keep $E_1$ fixed and move $E_2$, it is clear that the product $k_1k_2$ changes and clearly depends on $k$.. can you clarify?

Yes, by "tangent" I mean "slope", my bad. $E_1$ is not fixed, so as $E_2$. They move on the boundary of the ellipse and the line segement $E_1 E_2$ always crosses the focus  $F$. If you read my solution, you can see that wherever $E_1$ and $E_2$ move, the product of $k_1$ and $k_2$ always only depends on $a$ and $b$.

I think computations would be simpler by switching to the classical parameterization $(a \cos t,b \sin t)$

@JeanMarie Well I don't mean to use parameterization, but geometric and optical properties of conic sections.

I am surprized by the lack of homogeneity in the denominator of $\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 = \frac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 - a^2 b^2. } \end{equation}$ ; indeed, one should have for example $-2 a^3b$ instead of $-2a^3$.

@JeanMarie This is why my question is whether we can use geometric and/or optical properties of the ellipse to solve this question. If we can find a geometric way to solve that, we may be able to know the geometric meaning behind this strange value.

@JeanMarie I am trying to extract $a^2$ from the denominator and see what will happen. If we choose to use parameterization, we may not get the geometric meaning of that strange value.

The denominator $a^4 k^2 - a^2 k^2 b^2 - a^2 b^2 - 2 a^3 k^2 + a^4 k^2 + a^2 b^2$ should be $a^4 k^2 - a^2 k^2 b^2 - a^2 b^2 - 2 a^3 k^2\sqrt{a^2-b^2} + a^4 k^2 + a^2 b^2$. That explains the lack of homogeneity.

@jjagmath Thanks for pointing this out! This is my bad. I will soon correct it.

Geometric (but slightly algebra-heavy) Solution
(See the Edit History for a more complicated take.)
Changing some of OP's notation, consider a conic with focus $F$, focal chord $PQ$, and vertex $V$. For $X=P,Q,V$ and $x=p,q,v$, let the projection from $X$ onto the directrix be $X'$, with $|XX'|=x$; by the focus-directrix property of conics, $|XF|=ex$. For $X=P,Q$, let $X''$ be the projection of $X$ onto the line through $V$ parallel to the directrix; so $|XX''|=x-v$.

Defining $\theta:=\angle QPP'$, we find
$$p(1-e\cos\theta) \;=\; v(1+e) \;=\; q(1+e\cos\theta) \tag{G.1}$$
$$\to\qquad p\,\frac{1-e\cos\theta}{1+e} \;=\; v \;=\; q\,\frac{1+e\cos\theta}{1+e}\qquad\quad \tag{G.2}$$
$$\to\qquad
p-v = \frac{ep(1 + \cos\theta)}{1 + e} \qquad
q-v = \frac{eq(1 - \cos\theta)}{1 + e} \qquad\quad \tag{G.3}$$
whence the product of slopes of $VP$ and $VQ$ (taking the $y$-axis parallel to the directrix) is given by
$$-\frac{|VP''|}{|PP''|}\cdot\frac{|VQ''|}{|QQ''|}=-\frac{ep\sin\theta}{ep(1+\cos\theta)/(1+e)}\cdot\frac{eq\sin\theta}{eq(1-\cos\theta)/(1+e)}=-(1+e)^2\tag{G.4}$$
confirming OP's result. $\square$
The relations in $(G.3)$ seem like they want to be written in terms of half-angles:
$$
p-v = \frac{2ep\cos^2\frac12\theta}{1+e} \qquad
q-v = \frac{2eq\sin^2\frac12\theta}{1+e}
$$
but I'm not seeing a more-direct route to those expressions.

(Original) Parametric Solution
Using the focus-at-origin polar representation of a conic with focal half-width $p\;(=b^2/a)$ and eccentricity $e\;(=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}/a)$
$$r(\theta) = \frac{p}{1+e\cos\theta} \tag1$$ we can coordinatize $E_1$ and $E_2$ as
$$\begin{align}
E_1 &=r(\theta)\;(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=\left(\frac{p\cos\theta}{1+e\cos\theta},\frac{p\sin\theta}{1+e\cos\theta}\right) \\[8pt]
E_2 &=r(\theta+\pi)\;(\cos(\theta+\pi),\sin(\theta+\pi))=\left(\frac{-p\cos\theta}{1-e\cos\theta},\frac{-p\sin\theta}{1-e\cos\theta}\right)
\end{align} \tag2$$
while vertex $C$ is
$$C = r(0)\;(\cos 0, \sin 0) = \left(\frac{p}{1+e}, 0\right) \tag3$$
Writing $s:=\sin\theta$ and $c:=\cos\theta$, the product of the slopes of $CE_1$ and $CE_2$ can be calculated as
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(E_1-C)_y}{(E_1-C)_x}\cdot\frac{(E_2-C)_y}{(E_2-C)_x} &=
\frac{p s/(1 + ec)}{-p (1-c)/(1+e)/(1 + ec)}\cdot
\frac{-p s/(1-ec)}{-p (1 + c)/(1 + e)/(1 - ec)} \tag4\\[6pt]
&= -(1+e)^2\,\frac{\sin^2\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta} \tag5\\[6pt]
&= -(1+e)^2 \tag6
\end{align}$$
Since $e$ only depends upon $a$ and $b$, so does this product. $\square$

This matches OP's findings, as the expressions in the final cases reduce to the same result. Writing $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$, so that $a^2-b^2=a^2e^2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\left.\begin{array}{ccc}
\dfrac{-b^4}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} - a^2 b^2} 
&=& \dfrac{-a^4(1-e^2)^2}{2 a^4  - 2 a^3\cdot ae - a^2\cdot a^2(1-e^2)} \\[4pt]
\dfrac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2-b^2} - a)^2} 
&=& -\dfrac{a^4(1-e^2)^2}{a^2 (ae - a)^2}
\end{array} \right\} &= -\frac{a^4(1-e^2)^2}{a^4(1-e)^2} \tag7\\[4pt]
&= -(1+e)^2 \tag8
\end{align}$$

Addendum. As has been noted by @intelligentipauca's comment to OP's subsequent question about this property for a hyperbola (which is a bit redundant, given that this answer covers conics of arbitrary eccentricity ... but I digress ...), the constant-product-of-slopes property holds for endpoints of chords passing through any fixed point on the conic's major axis, not just the focus. Here's a quick outline of my Parametric Solution to cover this generalization:
Defining $E_i$ more generally as
$$E_i =r(2\theta_i)\;(\cos2\theta_i,\sin2\theta_i)=\left(\frac{p\cos2\theta_i}{1+e\cos2\theta_i},\frac{p\sin2\theta_i}{1+e\cos2\theta_i}\right) \tag{A.1}$$
one can show that the product of slopes of $CE_1$ and $CE_2$ is
$$k_1k_2 = \frac{(1 + e)^2}{\tan\theta_1 \tan\theta_2} \tag{A.2}$$
From here, one can also show that line $E_1E_2$ meets the $x$-axis (aka, the conic's major axis) at the point whose $x$-coordinate has the form
$$x = \frac{p (1 + \tan\theta_1 \tan\theta_2)}{e + 1 + (e-1)\tan\theta_1 \tan\theta_2} \tag{A.3}$$
This point is fixed when (and only when) $\tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2$ is constant; ie, whenn $k_1 k_2$ is constant. $\square$
I wonder: Is there a nice generalization for off-axis fixed points?

Thanks for your answer here! Though you didn’t use geometric or optical properties to do it, your final result which represents the weird value with eccentricity is really thought-provoking! I appreciate it very much!

@ZYX: Glad to help! ... I haven't investigated a geometric solution yet, but I suspect it will leverage the fact that the focal half-width of a conic is the harmonic mean of the sub-segments of a focal chord. See, for instance, this old answer of mine.

Will read and think more about it! Thanks again for your help here!

I am still looking for a solution using the concept of conjugate diameters (see here) where the polar angles $ \theta, \ \  \theta'$ of 2 conjugate diameters are such that $\tan \theta \tan \theta'= - \tfrac{b^2}{a^2}$ sounding very similar to the product of slopes we are after...

@JeanMarie Given the graph of the ellipse I used above in my post, let $P$ be an arbitrary point on the boundary of the ellipse. Then $\frac{-b^2}{a^2}$ is the product of the slopes of line segements $PA$ and $PC$. This was used as the second definition of an ellipse in the analytic geometry textbook that I used in highschool.

@JeanMarie I am reading the PDF that you attached in your comment, and that seems interesting. Could you please tell me the name and the author of that book? Thanks!

@ZYX In fact I have found this excerpt "as it is", without mention of any title and author. It looks to be printed around 1900.

@JeanMarie Have found the link to the book, and here it is: http://cdigital.dgb.uanl.mx/la/1020055683/ Click on "1020055683_001.pdf" and you will see the information for the book.

@JeanMarie And here is the link to this book on Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre09bowsgoog/page/n24/mode/2up

@ZYX Good catch ! I wasn't aware of this author (Edward Bowser)...

@Blue Thanks for your update of your answer! It is indeed algebra-heavy, but it shows us a possibility of solving it through geometric properties, and this gives us a very good insight into this problem! I really appreciate your efforts and help here!

I found a simple synthetic proof. Will post it soon.

This proof does not use coordinates, it is a synthetic one.
The idea is to reduce the problem to a simpler one about a circle. If we dilate our ellipse vertically with ratio $a/b$, it becomes a circle of radius $a$, as in the attached figure (left). By doing that, the points $E_1$ and $E_2$ become $P_1$ and $Q_1$. The slope of $k_1$ of $E_1C$ becomes the slope of $P_1C$, which equals $k_1'=\frac a{b}k_1$ and $k_2$ becomes $k_2'=\frac a{b}k_2$. Hence $k_1k_2=(\frac b{a})^2k_1'k_2'$. We need to prove that $k_1'k_2'$ is a constant for the circle on the right, independent of $P$ and $Q$, as long as the chord $PQ$ contains the focus $F$ (which can be any point, depending on the eccentricity of the initial ellipse).
In the right figure below, we set $\alpha=\angle PCO$ and $\beta=\angle OCQ$.
The goal is to prove that the product of the slopes of the red segments ($k_1'$ and $k_2'$) is independent of the chord $PQ$ as long as it passes through the given point $F$. It will depend solely on $OF=c$ and the radius of the circle, $a$.

By the law of sines
$$
\frac{PF}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{FC}{\sin CPQ};\qquad \frac{QF}{\sin\beta}=\frac{FC}{\sin PQC}\quad (*)
$$
Since $\angle QPC=\angle QDC$ and $\angle PQC=\angle PDC$ we have
$$
\sin \angle QPC=QC/2a;\qquad \sin\angle PQC=PC/2a
$$
($a$ is the radius of the circle). But from the isosceles triangles $\Delta POC$ and $\Delta COQ$ we see that
$$
\cos\beta=QC/2a;\qquad \cos\alpha=PC/2a,
$$
and therefore $\sin \angle QPC=\cos\beta$ and $\sin\angle PQC=\cos\alpha$.
Then, from the relations $(*)$ we derive
$$
\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\frac{PF\sin\angle QPC}{FC}\frac {QF\sin\angle PQC}{FC}= \frac{PF\cos\beta }{FC}\frac {QF\cos\alpha}{FC}
$$
or
$$
\tan\alpha\tan\beta=\frac{PF\cdot QF}{FC^2}.
$$
The quantity $PF\cdot QF$ is a constant (equal to the power of $F$), so choosing the chord as the diameter we get $PF\cdot QF=(a+c)(a-c)$. Also, $FC=a-c$ and therefore
$$
k_1'k_2'=-\tan\alpha\tan\beta=-\frac{a+c}{a-c}
$$
and, finally,
$$
k_1k_2=-\left(\frac b{a}\right)^2\frac{a+c}{a-c}=-\frac{(a+c)^2}{a^2}=-(1+e)^2,
$$
where $e$ is the eccentricity.
Remark: Observe that the proven property of the circle reduces to Thales' Theorem when the point $F$ is the center of the circle. It is a "generalized" Thales Theorem.

Thanks very much for your answer! Your synthetic method is really interesting and thought-provoking! I appreciate it very much!

You can also observe that the inscribed angles $\angle QPC$ and $\beta$ intercept arcs that add up to exactly a semicircle, so $\angle QPC+\beta=90^\circ$, so $\sin \angle QPC=\cos\beta$. Similarly for $\sin \angle PQC=\cos\alpha$. The formulas (*) are the big insight here; everything else follows from them. I like it.

@DavidK Good point. Thank you!

Whichever way you get to them, the point is that you observed that $\sin \angle QPC=\cos\beta$ and $\sin \angle PQC=\cos\alpha$ (OK, that's the second big insight in this answer, sorry I snubbed it before) so that you could do the substitutions in (*).

This is essentially a "Second Addendum" to my previous answer, provided separately to avoid sprawl. Moreover, it offers a generalization to the problem that seems to warrant separate consideration: not only can we move the fixed point of the chords off-axis, we can move endpoint $C$ of the "slope segments" off-vertex.


Let $C$ be any point on a conic, let $G$ be any point not on it, and $E_1E_2$ any chord passing through $G$. Project $E_i$, in the direction of $GC$, to $E_i'$ on the tangent to the conic at $C$. Then the product of the "oblique slopes" of $E_1C$ and $E_2C$
$$k := \frac{|CE_1'|}{|E_1E_1'|}\cdot \frac{|CE_2'|}{|E_2E_2'|} \tag{$\star$}$$
is a constant that depends only upon $C$ and $G$ (and the shape and size of the conic itself).

(Jump to "Final(?) Note" below for a better summary.)
To give an explicit value for $k$, place the configuration onto the coordinate plane with focus $F$ at the origin and associated vertex on the positive $x$-axis. Let $FC$ and $GC$ make angles of $2\gamma$ and $\gamma+\phi$ with the positive $x$-axis.

Then
$$k = \frac{|FC|^2}{p^2|GC|} \left(e^2-1 + \frac{2p}{|FC|}\right)  
\left(\begin{array}{l}
|GC|(1-e^2\cos^2(\gamma+\phi)) \\
\quad-2 |FC|( \cos(\gamma-\phi) + e\cos(\gamma+\phi))
\end{array} 
\right)\tag{$\star\star$}$$
where $e$ is the conic's eccentricity and $p$ is its focal half-width (aka, semi-latus rectum).
(Sanity check: Taking $\gamma=\phi=0$ and $G=F$, matching the case stated in the original question, we have that $|GC|=|FC|=p/(1+e)$, and the above reduces to $k=-(1+e)^2$.)

Currently, the only proof I have is a tedious coordinate bash based, as in my previous answer, on the polar representation of a focus-at-origin conic:
$$r(\theta) = \frac{p}{1+e\cos\theta} \tag1$$
Taking
$$C:=r(2\theta)(\cos2\gamma,\sin2\gamma) \qquad E_i := r(2(\gamma+\theta_i))\,(\cos2(\gamma+\theta_i),
\sin2(\gamma+\theta_i)) \tag2$$
and
$$u:=\frac{(-\sin2\gamma,e-\cos2\gamma)}{\sqrt{1+e^2+2e\cos2\gamma}} \qquad v:=(\cos(\gamma+\phi),\sin(\gamma+\phi)) \tag3$$ which are unit vectors, the first tangent to the conic at $C$, and the second in direction $\overrightarrow{GC}$, one can show
$$C-E_i = m_i u + n_i v$$
where
$$\begin{align}
m_i &= -\frac{
2 p \sin^2\theta_i \sqrt{1 + e^2 + 2 e \cos2\gamma} 
\left(
\cot\theta_i (\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e\cos(\gamma+\phi)) - \sin(\gamma - \phi)
\right)}{(1 + e \cos2\gamma) 
(\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi)) (1 + e \cos2(\gamma+\theta_i))} \\[4pt]
n_i &= \frac{2 p \sin^2\theta_i}{(\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi)) (1 + e \cos2 (\gamma+\theta_i))}
\end{align} \tag4$$
giving $E_iC$ an "oblique slope" of
$$\begin{align}
k_i := \frac{m_i}{n_i} &= -\frac{\sqrt{1 + e^2 + 2 e \cos2\gamma} (\cot\theta_i (\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi)) - \sin(\gamma-\phi)}{1 + e \cos2\gamma} \\[4pt]
&= -\sigma\;(\cot\theta_i (\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi)) - \sin(\gamma - \phi)) \\[4pt]
\text{with}\quad \sigma &:= \sqrt{\frac{|FC|^2}{p^2}
(e^2 - 1)+ 2\frac{|FC|}{p}}
\end{align} \tag5$$
where that last form follows from $|FC|=r(2\gamma)$.
Further, with $C-G=|GC|v$, where $G$ is where chord $E_1E_2$ meets the line through $C$ in direction $v$. One can show
$$|GC| = \frac{2|FC| \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{\cos(\gamma - \phi+\theta_1+\theta_2) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi) \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}\tag{6}$$
Expanding $(6)$ and writing it in terms of $\cot\theta_i$, which in turn can be expressed in terms of $k_i$ from $(5)$, one finds
$$|GC| = \frac{2 |FC| (\cos(\gamma-\phi) + e \cos(\gamma+\phi))}{
   \dfrac{k_1k_2}{\sigma^2} - (1 - e^2 \cos^2(\gamma+\phi))} \tag{7}$$
which, with $k:=k_1k_2$, is equivalent to $(\star\star)$. Finally, we observe that $G$ is thus fixed when and only when $k$ is constant. $\square$

Final(?) Note. Here's the cleanest rendition of the overall phenomenon I have found, making no reference to angles or even the conic's eccentricity.
Extend $GC$ to chord $C'C$ and introduce parallel focal chord $D'D$. Also, projecting $F$ onto $F'$ on the tangent line at $C$, let $k_0$ be the "oblique slope" of $FC$: $$k_0 := \frac{|\overrightarrow{CF'}|}{|\overrightarrow{FF'}|} \tag{N.1}$$
(I'm being a bit more careful about signed lengths here, using the arrow to indicate the direction of a given segment, and assigning opposite signs to opposite directions; eg, $|\overrightarrow{XY}|=-|\overrightarrow{YX}|$. In particular here, we're interested mostly in segments parallel to $GC$ and to the tangent at $C$. I'll let $|\overrightarrow{GC}|$ and $|\overrightarrow{CF'}|$ dictate the "positive" directions of such segments. I'll take $|FC|$ to be unsigned.)

Then,

$$\frac{1}{k_1k_2}\frac{|\overrightarrow{GC'}|}{|\overrightarrow{GC}|} \;=\; \frac{1}{k_0^2} 
\frac{(\rho_C + \rho_D) (1 + \rho_C \rho_D)}{(1 + \rho_D)^2} \qquad \rho_X := \frac{|\overrightarrow{FX'}|}{|\overrightarrow{FX}|} \tag{N.2}$$

The value of right-hand side of the relation is completely determined by chord $C'C$ (which determines chord $D'D$), and thus is constant relative to that chord. The left-hand side is determined by the position of $G$ on that chord, with $k_1k_2$ determined by arbitrary chords $E_1E_2$ through $G$: If $G$ is fixed, then $k_1k_2$ is constant, as claimed.
One should observe that the relation is a bit problematic for, say, a parabola with chord $GC$ parallel to the axis (sending $C'$ and $D'$ off to infinity); likewise for $GC$ parallel to an asymptote in a hyperbola. Finding the appropriate limiting forms of the relation are currently left as an exercise to the reader. (A Final-er Note from me may be in order.)

If I were a little more adept at projective geometry I might be able to extend my answer to the question about the hyperbola to cover this case. It might want two projections.

@DavidK: I agree that there seems to be a projective character to this result; it might even be "obvious" in that context. I haven't had much of a chance to look at this even synthetically, but wanted to go ahead and get the coordinatized form out of my head.

What I did for the other question involved a central projection (which comes naturally from the cone of the conic section) but it’s basically synthetic.

@Blue Thanks again for your new answer! This time you have offered very interesting result and I will read that carefully.

Since our firend @Blue has posted the most generalized version of this problem about conic section, I have made an attempt on using analytic geometry to solve the generalized case for an ellipse, and here is my attempt.


$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $E_1 E_2$ be any arbitrary chord in the ellipse, and let $P:(x_3,y_3)$ be an arbitrary point on the boundary of the ellipse. Redefine $k_1,k_2$ to be slopes of $PE_2,PE_2$ respectively. What is the new $k_1k_2$ ?

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
This time we only consider the most generalized case where the slope of the straight line is not infinity.
Since here $E_1E_2 $ is any arbitrary chord in the ellipse, we set the function of the straight line to be
\begin{equation} y = mx + n \tag{16.2.1} \end{equation}
Combining it with the equation of the ellipse, we have
$$\begin{cases}
    b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \\
    \\
    y = mx + n
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
    &\Rightarrow (a^2 m^2 + b^2)x^2 + 2a^2 m n x + a^2(n^2-b^2) = 0 \\
    &\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
                    x_1 + x_2 = \frac{-2a^2 m n}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} \\
                    \\
                    x_1 x_2 = \frac{a^2(n^2-b^2)}{a^2 m^2 + b^2}
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
So we get
\begin{equation} x_1 + x_2 = \frac{-2a^2 m n}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} \tag{16.2.2} \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} x_1 x_2 = \frac{a^2(n^2-b^2)}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} \tag{16.2.3} \end{equation}
Therefore, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
    k_1 k_2 &= \frac{(y_1-y_3)(y_2-y_3)}{(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)} \\
            &= \frac{y_1 y_2 - y_3(y_1 + y_2) + y_3^2}{x_1 x_2 - x_3(x_1 + x_2) + x_3^2} \\
            &= \frac{m^2 x_1 x_2 + (mn-my_3) (x_1 + x_2) + (y_3 - n)^2}{x_1 x_2 - x_3(x_1 + x_2) + x_3^2} \\
            &= \frac{\frac{a^2 m^2 (n^2-b^2)}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} + \frac{-2a^2 m n(mn-my_3)}{a^2 m^2 + b^2}+ (y_3 - n)^2}{\frac{a^2(n^2-b^2)}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} - \frac{-2a^2 x_3 m n}{a^2 m^2 + b^2} + x_3^2} \\
            &= \frac{a^2 m^2 (n^2-b^2)-2a^2 m n(mn-my_3)+ (y_3 - n)^2 (a^2 m^2 + b^2)}{a^2(n^2-b^2) + 2a^2 x_3 m n + x_3^2(a^2 m^2 + b^2)} \\
            &= \frac{a^2 m^2 (y_3^2 - b^2) + b^2(y_3-n)^2}{b^2(x_3^2-a^2)+a^2(mx_3+n)^2}
\end{aligned}$$
Then since from the equation of the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
we have
$$y^2 - b^2 = -\frac{b^2 x^2}{a^2}$$
and
$$x_2 - a^2 = -\frac{a^2 y^2}{b^2},$$
we get
$$\begin{aligned}
    k_1 k_2 &= \frac{a^2 m^2 (y_3^2 - b^2) + b^2(y_3-n)^2}{b^2(x_3^2-a^2)+a^2(mx_3+n)^2} \\
            &= \frac{b^2[(y_3-n)^2 - m^2 x_3^2]}{a^2[(mx_3+n)^2 - y_3^2]}   \\
            &= \frac{b^2}{a^2} \frac{(y_3-n+mx_3)(y_3-n-mx_3)}{(mx_3+n+y_3)(mx_3+n-y_3)} \\
            &= \frac{-b^2}{a_2} \frac{(mx_3 + y_3 - n)(mx_3-y_3+n)}{(mx_3+y_3+n)(mx_3-y_3+n)} \\
            &= (e^2-1)  \frac{mx_3 + y_3 - n}{mx_3+y_3+n}
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, we have the final result as
\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 = (e^2-1)  \frac{mx_3 + y_3 - n}{mx_3+y_3+n} \tag{16.2.4} \end{equation}

Let's do a test for the final result $(16.2.4)$: If we let $n=-mc, x_3 = a, y_3 = 0$,  then we are back to our original problem, and we have
$$\begin{aligned}
k_1 k_2 &= (e^2-1)  \frac{mx_3 + y_3 - n}{mx_3+y_3+n} \\
        &= (e^2-1)  \frac{ma + mc}{ma - mc} \\
        &= (e^2-1)  \frac{a + c}{a - c} \\
        &= (e-1)(e+1)  \frac{1 + e}{1 - e} \\
        &= -(e+1)^2
\end{aligned}$$
which is exactly what we get in the original problem.
